# Mono obtain remote ip address when socket is timed out

Tags: c#, mono

```
catch (SocketException se)
{
    if(se.ErrorCode == 10054 || se.ErrorCode == 10053) // Error code for Connection reset by peer
    {
        Console.WriteLine("User from " + currentSocket.RemoteEndPoint.ToString() + " timed out");
    }
}
```

I have a problem with socket exception with mono, above code runs perfectly on windows, while on mono throws exception that RemoteEndPoint is null.
My question is how to obtain ip address of disconnected user using mono?

Comment: what's `currentSocket`?

Answer (score 0):

Create a wrapper which holds the socket and any additional information you need. Upon connection, you can populate the values you want to save such as their ip address. When a disconnect occurs, you can log from this variable instead of off the socket object.